# How to code FULLTEXT search in mysql using variables?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

There is a column called `comment` in my data table, and a column with all word segmentations in another table. Now I wanna use the segmentation column to **FULLTEXT** search the data table. In the past I used constants to search in boolean mode and work normally.

Now I get `[Err] 1210 - Incorrect arguments to AGAINST` by using variable to search just like this:

`select * from comment where match(comment) against (keyword.keyword in boolean mode);`

Does MySQL support **FULLTEXT** search with variables? Do I need to use a MySQL function?

**ADD:**

For example, here are two tables, one contains comments, another contains the keywords used to query:

```
    comment table
id       comment
1   I think it looks fine
2   good quality cup
3   useful functions
4   it's healthy
5   bad workmanship

    keyword table
id      keyword
1       fantastic 
2       fine
3       good
4       useful
5       bad
6       wonderful
7       great
```

I expect the result is in comment table where id=1,2,3,5. One of the comments below this question reminds me of iterating every keyword to get consts. Is there any better idea?

Comment: Take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847899/stopwords-and-mysql-boolean-fulltext

Comment: `b.cate` is not a variable, it's a column name.  More context is needed to understand what you are actually trying to accomplish, because this query as written isn't a working query... in the sense that it would not likely get as far as the error you're showing.

Comment: @deadman sorry, the post you put on is about doing FULLTEXT search when the column having some keywords of MySQL. But I just want to know how to execute FULLTEXT search with a dynamic column instead of consts.

Comment: @Michael - sqlbot so how to iterate a column to get consts and put them in FULLTEXT query with only one SQL? or I need to realize a MySQL function by myself?

Comment: @Michael - sqlbot I 've edited the question, please have a look, thanks.